# Writing C#-like extensions in JavaScript for Knockout Observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Consider the following code:

```
if (countriesLookup()) {
    countriesLookup().fill(initialData.Countries);
} else {
    const subscription = countriesLookup.subscribe(function (lookup) {
        lookup.fill(initialData.Countries);
        subscription.dispose();
    });
}
```

Here I have a ko.observable `countriesLookup`. If by the moment of data initialization the component itself is not initialized yet (`countriesLookup() == undefined`), I subscribe to that observable, and when it finally get the component, I perform initialization with initial data and get rid of subscription.

Let's forget for the moment that this approach leads to callback hell etc. etc., and consider possible ways to make this less ugly.

I wanted to write something like C# extensions to observable that would be like that in use:

```
countriesLookup.initialize(x => x.fill(initialData.Countries));
```

And the implementation supposes to look like that:

```
ko.observable.prototype.initialize = function(initializeFunc) {
    const currentValue = ???
    if (currentValue()) {
        initializeFunc(currentValue());
    } else {
        const subscription = currentValue.subscribe(function (lookup) {
            initializeFunc(lookup);
            subscription.dispose();
        });
    }
}
```

Obviously, that does not work, especially because I am not sure if this is possible to get the current value of observable inside the "extension" method.

I am currently thinking in terms of C# programming, where I am somewhat proficient, and would like very much some advice on how I should write such extension.

---

Perhaps I should explain my problems a bit more. I am aware that the current value could be retrieved with `this` inside the method added to prototype, but the problem is in the fact that observable returns a function.

For example this

```
String.prototype.SayHi = function SayHi() {
    return "Hi " + this + "!";
};
"blah".SayHi();      //return "Hi blah!"
```

works just fine, but this

```
ko.observable.prototype.SayHi = function SayHi() {
    return "Hi " + this + "!";
};
var a = ko.observable("blah")
a.SayHi();
```

fails with the following error:

`VM543:1 Uncaught TypeError: a.SayHi is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:3`

I hope it added some clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your point, your aim is to add a custom function for the observables.
In that case you should use `fn` instead of `prototype`.
Check out this link: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html

> I am not sure if this is possible to get the current value of observable inside the "extension" method

And you can get the current value of your observable using this method, thus your above example is very close to what you want.

```js
ko.observable.fn.initialize = function(initializeFunc) {
  const currentValue = this;
  if (currentValue()) {
    initializeFunc(currentValue());
  } else {
    const subscription = currentValue.subscribe(function(lookup) {
      initializeFunc(lookup);
      subscription.dispose();
    });
  }
  return this;
}

var ViewModel = function() {
  this.data = ko.observable().initialize(x => console.log("Value changed to: " + x));
  this.data("100");
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

================================
**NOTE:** There is a discussion on why `fn` is used instead of `prototype` and someone pointed in there that it is better to use [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) for some performance reasons.
Read it here: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/979

Comment: Great job, Adrian! Thank you very much!